# UserManager.FindByNameAsync slow in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, authentication, asp.net-membership

I have a site based on ASP.NET MVC framework. Although i am using async method to login the user, i have found that it takes forever to get user logged in into the site. I have used Visual Studio's diagnostic tools and found that this line takes most of the time during the code execution.

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
```

**Full Code:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var getPasswordResult = UserManager.CheckPassword(user, model.Password);

            if (getPasswordResult)
            {
                AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

                var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(
                          user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

                AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = model.RememberMe }, identity);

                if (model.RememberMe == true)
                {
                    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UsersLogin");
                    cookie.Values.Add("UserName", model.Email);
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                }



                return RedirectToAction("NavigateAuthUser", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Any suggestion to improve the performance?
Thanks
Sanjeev

Comment: Also saw this issue, click on Login button takes 1 sec.

Answer (score 3):

For **workaround** I use:

```
 _db.Users.First(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
```

But I'm sure this is not the best way

Answer (score 1):

Develop my own method FindByEmail, this way I greatly improve the perfomance

```
    public AspNetUsers FindByEmail(string Email)
    {
        try
        {
            var _modelo = new SIGMAEntities();

            return _modelo.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email.Trim().ToLower() == Email);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```